# iPhone 6.0 simulator not showing home button or frames

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

When I run the iOS Simulator (iPhone running iOS 6.0), it does not show the home button or frames.

I have installed Mac OS X and Xcode on a VMware instance.

[image: iOS Simulator without the hardware home button or frames]

Comment: I just got an MBP 15 retina and freshly installed Xcode.  The frame was showing up for the 1st week of use.  I just rotated the iPhone for the first time.  The frame went away and I can't get it back.  strange.

Answer (score 15):

Increase the scale of iPhone simulator to 100% Or

other option is Use **Command window+shift+h**

this will work like you press home button

Comment: thanks but i reduce the resolution of my mac so this solve my problem.

Comment: OMG! That's so obscure and unnecessary. Curse you, Apple! And thanks, @Sachin

Answer (score 7):

*There isn't any Home button or Frame for iPhone 5 (iOS 6).*

*To go to the Home Screen do these Steps:*

> 1. Simulator
> 2. Hardware
> 3. Home

*The only Possible way to get the frame is taking the iPhone simulator screenshot and then Cropping it in a iPhone 5 frame in Photoshop.*

Comment: but in my office simulator has home button and frames.

Comment: It's probably the iPhone 4/4S.

Comment: The iPhone 5 doesn't have frame or home button.

Comment: Currently just under Hardware > home

Answer (score 4):

Once the simulator is open press **Command+1**

Answer (score 2):

Try clicking command+2 button to enlarge try for command+1, command+3. see the different sizes. Check if the simulator app is selected.