# Why is Home button missing in retina display iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

The latest iOS on which I worked was ios 4.3. However continuing with iOS development now, on switching to iOS 6 I found a lot of different features. One interesting and confusing feature is the new look of iphone simulator. It has a new shape and does not have home button. I was looking at [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550179/iphone-6-0-simulator-not-show-home-button-and-frames) link and learnt that this was true for devices after iPhone 4 including it.
My question is, why is home button absent for new iphone simulators not considering that former would appear after scaling the latter.

Comment: i bet it's just to avoid to use more pixels: new devices has bigger screen size (retina) and on some mac display they may go out of border, as on my old MacBook Pro...

Comment: @meronix : Thanks for sharing the info. But iphone 4 has the same screen size as the previous versions. Only iphone 5 has a bigger screen size if I am not wrong. Then why is the above statement true for iPhone 4?

Comment: They've decided not to use precious pixels of your screen anymore for a home button, instead, use the key-binding shift-command-H

Comment: iphone 4 may be retina too... that is 480x2 = 960 pixels in height. My screen has just 900 pixels in vertical... and on my screen the "home button" shows on iPhone non-retina... and NOT when i choose a retina simulator (both 3.5" and 4")

Comment: Got more close to what you both are saying. @meronix : Even if iPhone 4 retina display has same screen size as previous iPhones, even then size of simulator will be more because of more pixels per area. Please correct me if I am wrong from what you are suggesting.

Comment: well... technically speaking, iPhone 4 retina display (960x640) has NOT the screen size of iphone 3 non-retina (480x320). It's just an Apple idea to let you believe your code (when it ask the iOS API) that it's always 480x320 (but telling you that avery "pixel" is drawing at double resolution). it's an apple choice, to let old apps run on retina displays.

Comment: Ok. So what change will be there in the code I have to make for taking care of retina and non retina displays ?

Comment: it depends: for imageView (let's say 100x100 pixel) loading image just add 2 files, 1 normal (yourFile.png 100x100) and 1 retina (yourFile@2x.png 200x200, just call it that way,that's all), and iOs will use / load / draw the correct file for you, you don't need to do anything more.In general, for UIViews, just forget about retina, and think always you are in a 480x320 display, iOs will draw in high resolution for you (that's what it make the apple idea a GOOD idea... you just write the most of the code as if you are on 480x320 display)but this is one other question:tons of question here around

Comment: Great !! That seems simple. Thanks meronix for your inputs. :) I request you to draft an answer for this question which can be viewed later on as a reference.

Comment: @meronix : Quite a straightforward reply !! Your wish.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

there is a option of Home button

1) it gives shortcut for Home button = <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>
2) it gives three size of simulator =  (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>)

Answer (score 4):

you can switch size of ios simulator (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>)

Comment: Thanks Liolik. However I was more interested in the why part rather than how part. :)

Comment: In humble opinion I think it is to preserve precious screen space, because retina size becomes scrollable on small displays. It obviously must be stupid to also include iphone casing/home button to be scrollable :)

Answer (score 2):

It also depends on your screen resolution. On my MBP Retina it displays the frame for all the device, on my external monitor (1600 x 1200) it fails to show the frame for all the Retina simulated devices.